# Where is comment admistration template located?

Tags: comments, theming

I have a `Drupal 7` sub-theme based on `Bootstrap 3` theme, the comment admin page (http://www.example.com/comment/46849/edit?destination=admin/content/comment/approval) looks as shown below. It is however missing the ability to edit `Author` and `Url` fields. I would like to know which template file I need to edit to get this functionality.

[image: Comment Admin Page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following custom css in my sub-theme fixed this:

```
.region-content .comment-form fieldset.collapsible {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width:100%;
}

body .region-content .comment-form div fieldset.panel.panel-default .panel-heading {
display:block;
width:100%;
}
body .comment-form div .panel-collapse.collapse.fade {
display:block;
}

.comment-form div .form-item.form-item-subject.form-type-textfield.form-group {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If, for some reason, the whole Author fieldset is hidden, be sure to check the HTML first, then you can also use the devel module for some dpm-ing in `yourtheme_form_comment_form_alter`.

Something like this should force the fieldset to be rendered:

```
function yourtheme_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) { 
  $form['author']['#access'] = user_access('administer comments');
}
```

Comment: Checked the HTML and strangely the html to display these fields is there, see - https://dpaste.de/ZgzJ , it's just not displaying !!!

Comment: Check your CSS then, you said the fieldset was displayed with another theme so there's something in Bootstrap or your custom CSS that hides it. Use Firebug or any other browser inspector to check what CSS is applied.

Answer (score 2):

As a partial alternative to the "comment admin page" which is "missing the ability to edit Author and Url fields": how about using something like the "Seven" theme as your "Administration theme"? By using that theme, and navigating to `admin/content/comment`, you can use the "edit" link to the right, so that you'll be able to edit fields like "Author" from there.

For the sake of completenes, be aware that there is a [Bootstrap issue about styling comments](https://www.drupal.org/node/2109369) which I believe is somehow related to this question (current status = postphoned). And it has this related issue: [Add a comment.tpl.php to base theme](https://www.drupal.org/node/2335939), in which it says "There is no comment.tpl.php in the base themes, so it is pulled from core."

According to the first issue, it seems that it might be a good idea to use some of the typical alternatives for styling comments using bootstrap, or any of its sub-themes. I.e. something like [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) or [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds).

Comment: This seems a smart way around, I did this with `Use the administration theme when editing or creating content` setting but as soon as I click the edit link of a comment I get transferred to a url like `http://www.example.com/comment/46899/edit?destination=admin/content/comment/approval` and it switches to Bootstrap theme.

Comment: Thx for somehow confirming this as a work around. Not sure if I correctly understand your comment here, but what happens if you DO NOT check that checkbox in front of that "Use the admin ... creating content"? From yor comment it seems to me that you have it checked, or am I missing something?

Comment: There is no change whether it is checked or not. As soon as we navigate to comment editing screen drupal thinks we are no longer in `admin` section and applies the bootstrap theme. The problem seems to be with `Bootstrap` the code `<legend class="panel-heading">
              <a href="#edit-author" class="panel-title fieldset-legend" data-toggle="collapse">Administration</a>
            </legend>
            <div id="edit-author" class="panel-collapse collapse fade">` not rendering the `Panel` for some reason, if the panel is rendered it can be clicked to `un-collapse` the required content.

Comment: Wow, that is really bizarre. Not sure if it would be of any help, but do you think via https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey you can somehow resolve this? Just a wild guess, but one never knows ...

Comment: Or could be smartly done with the help of the implementation of the `hook_custom_theme`, check if it is a comment page, and return the `seven` theme. This should be done in a custom module.

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit author of the comment. Why would you want to change the name of the person who wrote the comment anyways? Unless... you want to allow anonymous user's to post comments, you would have to go into user permissions and check box that field.

If you want to add the ability for urls, you need to install a module for that.

Such as [Wysiwyg](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) or my personal favorite [CK Editor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor)

Comment: I need to remove url's of comment in case they look spammy or risky for others.

Comment: If you don't want to allow urls at all, then you need to edit your comment body field and change the Text Processing from Filtered HTML to Plain text.

Comment: For example, if your content type is called Articles, you go to yourwebsite.com/admin/structure/types/manage/articles/comment/fields  then press the edit link for comment body

Comment: I want url's but don't want spammy ones.

Comment: Then you would need someone to modarate the comments and just edit the comment and delete the spammy url or delete the entire comment.

Comment: OK I think this is what you want. In yoursite.com/admin/people/permissions/roles you would create a new role, call it Moderator and in permissions yoursite.com/admin/people/permissions, just give the Moderator role the permission to "Administer comments and comment settings"

Comment: I already have those permissions, I can edit the comment content and subject. It's just it does not displays the fields to do the same for url and author. On the same setup my old theme 'Litejazz` allows me to do that.

Comment: ok try this. Go to drupal\themes\bartik\templates and copy Bartik's comment.tpl.php and comment-wrapper.tpl.php and put it on your theme's templates folder, clear the cache and see if this allows you to see those fields now.

Comment: Copying the template files had no visible changes to the comment moderation fields.